# How auto update nicescroll cursor position with WP Infinite Scroll?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

Link to scripts:

nicescroll.js - http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll

WP Infinite Scroll - http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

After "infinite scroll" has displayed new content, you have to call `$(window).getNiceScroll().resize()` (you need new version 2.5.0 of nicescroll)

For older versions you need to call `$(window).getNiceScroll().onResize()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("#html").scrollTop({ x: 0, y: 0 });
```